# LaTeX: Forcing a very wide longtable to fit textwidth

Tags: tables, longtable

All,

Having been through everything I can find here and trying all of them - I'm still stuck. 
I have a very wide multipage landscape table that I want to throw in a thesis appendix. I just can't seem to force it to fit textwidth. Help would be definitely appreciated.

Example:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}

\caption[etc]{etc} \\
   \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Ref & DOI & Authors & Year & Title & Journal or Publisher & Volume & Pages\\
   \hline
   \endhead
   \hline
   \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{continued \ldots}\\
   \endfoot
   \endlastfoot
   \hline

1 & 10.1007/BF00628820 & Akaogi, M.; Navrotsky, A. & 1987  & Calorimetric Study of High-Pressure Phase Transitions Among the CdGeO$_{3}$ Polymorphs (Pyroxenoid, Garnet, Ilmenite, and Perovskite Structures) & Physics and Chemistry of Minerals & 14 & 435-440\\

...

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Help would be massively appreciated. 
Edit: is there a way multirow could be used so I could manually wrap text to fit?

Comment: Hi! Can you please post your preamble? So we know a bit more about your page dimensions etc.

Comment: A compilable example would be even more comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

The main part of the `longtable` that controls the width is the part that you omitted from your example.

`\begin{longtable}`

on its own is a syntax error.

given

```
1 & 10.1007/BF00628820 & Akaogi, M.; Navrotsky, A. & 1987  & Calorimetric Study of High-Pressure Phase Transitions Among the CdGeO$_{3}$ Polymorphs (Pyroxenoid, Garnet, Ilmenite, and Perovskite Structures) & Physics and Chemistry of Minerals & 14 & 435-440\\
```

I would guess you want something like

```
\begin{longtable}{lll
                  >{\raggedright}p{3cm}
                  >{\raggedright}p{4cm}
                  >{\raggedright}p{3cm}
                  rr}
```

and adjust the widths to fit. (You need `\usepackage{array}` for the `>` syntax).

Answer (score 3):

For such longtables use

```
...
\usepackage{xltabular}
...

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lllXXXrrr}
...
\end{xltabular}
```

The `xltabular` now can have pagebreaks and the same definitions as the longtable. A caption is also possible.